# residual waiting time and spent time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, queueing-theory, renewal-processes

Does the expected value of the [residual time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_time) (the amount of time one has to wait) equal the expected value of the spent time (the amount of time since the last arrival)? I know that the expected value of the residual time for a general distribution is $\frac{E[X^2]}{2E[X]}$, where $X$ is a r.v. denoting the time between events. Unsure for the spent time though.

Comment: Assuming the interrenewal distribution is non-lattice, the limiting distribution of the age and residual time are the same (and so their expectations as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in comments; yes, their distributions are the same. [This article](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2018/09/13/waiting-time-paradox/) talks about it in more detail for anyone interested.